Siesta MD Nose: E_tot total Energy increase drift
I want to calculate binding energies/adsorption energies and therefore I did siesta simulations (Type: Nose (Ensemble: NVT), target Temperature: 300K, Nose mass 100, timestep 2fs).
From the MDE-files I obtained the pressure, Temperature, $E_{KS}$, Volume and E_tot for about 3000 timesteps. All the values fluctuate around a rather stable mean value. Only $E_{tot}$ is showing a slight and constant increasing drift. I can not explain this. Isn’t the definition of $E_{tot} = E_{pot} + E_{kin}$?
As far as I understood, the $E_{KS}$ is defined as the potential energy of the molecule and the temperature describes the kinetic Energy ($E_{kin} = f/2 * k_B * T$). If this is true and because T and $E_{KS}$ have a constant mean value, I don’t understand the $E_{tot}$ drift.
How is $E_{tot}$ calculated and which energy components are taken into account? I would be happy about any hints!
